# Postresql: for loop over every id in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I have following script:

```
do
$do$
begin
    FOR i IN 1..450 LOOP
        if (1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i)
        and 1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER') )
            then raise notice 'id % :  owner only', i;
        elsif(0< (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i) )
            then 
                if(not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'APPLICANT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding applicant role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'APPLICANT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EXPERT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding expert role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EXPERT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding owner role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'OWNER');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'ADMIN'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding admin role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'ADMIN');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'HEAD'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding head role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'HEAD');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EMPLOYEE'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding employee role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EMPLOYEE');
                end if;
                if(  EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  removing recommender role', i; delete from document_configuration_role dc where dc.document_configuration_id = i and dc.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER';
                end if;
                if(  6 = (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  all roles assigned', i; 
                end if;
        else
            raise notice 'id % :  not existing', i;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
$do$
```

I have declared an hardcoded iterator here(from 1 to 450), but I want to iterate only through document_configuration_role.document_configuration_id, how to achieve that?

I tried something like below with declare i record:

```
do
$do$
declare i record;
begin
    FOR i IN (select dcr2.document_configuration_id from document_configuration_role dcr2) LOOP
        if (1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i)
        and 1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER') )
            then raise notice 'id % :  owner only', i;
        elsif(0< (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i) )
            then 
                if(not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'APPLICANT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding applicant role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'APPLICANT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EXPERT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding expert role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EXPERT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding owner role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'OWNER');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'ADMIN'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding admin role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'ADMIN');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'HEAD'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding head role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'HEAD');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EMPLOYEE'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding employee role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EMPLOYEE');
                end if;
                if(  EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  removing recommender role', i; delete from document_configuration_role dc where dc.document_configuration_id = i and dc.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER';
                end if;
                if(  6 = (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  all roles assigned', i; 
                end if;
        else
            raise notice 'id % :  not existing', i;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
$do$
```

but it shows me error:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = record
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might
> need to add explicit type casts.   Where: PL/pgSQL function
> inline_code_block line 5 at IF

Do You have any suggestion how to iterate only through ids from table?

Comment: Does select dcr2.document_configuration_id from document_configuration_role dcr2 returns scaler value? What's the value? and what's the data type of select document_configuration_id ?

Comment: You have declared `i` to be a `record`. In order to get at `document_configuration_id` you need to do `i.document_configuration_id`. If all you need to use is `document_configuration_id` then declare `i` to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only pulling the configuration_id from your query into i.

Try declaring i as a bigint instead of a record.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through all **document_configuration_id** from **document_configuration_role** (assigning to i) then declare i with the datatype of document_configuration_id (i assumed it as bigint).

```
do $$
declare i bigint;

begin
FOR i IN
   select dcr2.document_configuration_id from document_configuration_role dcr2
LOOP  
        if (1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i)
        and 1= (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER') )
            then raise notice 'id % :  owner only', i;
        elsif(0< (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i) )
            then 
                if(not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'APPLICANT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding applicant role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'APPLICANT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EXPERT'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding expert role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EXPERT');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'OWNER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding owner role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'OWNER');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'ADMIN'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding admin role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'ADMIN');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'HEAD'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding head role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'HEAD');
                end if;
                if( not EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'EMPLOYEE'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  adding employee role', i; insert into document_configuration_role values (i, 'EMPLOYEE');
                end if;
                if(  EXISTS (select (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i and  dcr.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER'))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  removing recommender role', i; delete from document_configuration_role dc where dc.document_configuration_id = i and dc.role_name like 'RECOMMENDER';
                end if;
                if(  6 = (select count (dcr.role_name) from document_configuration_role dcr where dcr.document_configuration_id = i))
                    then raise notice 'id % :  all roles assigned', i; 
                end if;
        else
            raise notice 'id % :  not existing', i;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;$$
```